# Obtaining the status code of an http request when an exception is thrown (in c#)

Tags: c#, http, exception, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using an instance of the `HttpWebRequest` class to send a request and receive a response from a website. 
In case an exception thrown is a `WebException`, i can retrieve the http status code by typecasting the `WebException` as `((HttpWebResponse)exc.Response).StatusCode;`. 
How can i do the same for other types of exceptions, such as `UriFormatException`?

Comment: If there's a `UriFormatException` I wouldn't expect the request to be made at all, so what status code could there be?

Comment: Are all possible errors generated during an HTTP request accounted for in the WebException class?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not necessarily - there could be a network failure for example... But again, in that case there wouldn't be a response to report. I suspect by the time there's a response, it will be a WebException.

Comment: Thank you jon and CodeCaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UriFormatException would mean that the URL you're trying to access isn't a valid URL, so there won't be any status code, because there is not a request.